# Rxjs subscribe not working for routed components

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have angular2 v4.0.1 project where I am using component router for routes. I am trying to make a shared (singleton) service that will serve as data storage for all the components. If a single component updates a value of the service, Others will have that. But somehow `subscribe` is not firing if the component is not a child of parent component.

I have a main AppComponent.ts and other components are loaded via component router.

I am not using individual provider for each component, I am injecting the service in @NgModule declaration at root module.

#### AppComponent.ts

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule,JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { ConfirmComponent } from './confirm.component';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { OtherComponent }  from './other.component';
import { SomeComponent }  from './some.component';
import { PlaceholderDirective } from './directives/placeholder.directive';

import { StorageService } from "./storage.service";

//app routes
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path:'', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path:'home',component:AppComponent},
    {path:'other',component:OtherComponent},
    {path:'some',component:SomeComponent},
]

@NgModule({
  imports:      [  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),BrowserModule, HttpModule,JsonpModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, OtherComponent,SomeComponent, ConfirmComponent,PlaceholderDirective ],
  providers:[StorageService],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  entryComponents: [
        ConfirmComponent
      ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### StorageService.ts

```js
import {Injectable,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
  name: any;

  nameChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Jack";
  }
  change(){
    this.name = 'Jane';
    this.nameChange.next(this.name);
  }

}
```

#### SomeComponent.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from "./storage.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'some',
  template: `<p>{{storage.name}}</p><a (click)='change();'>Change</a>`,
})

export class SomeComponent  { 
    constructor(
        private storage : StorageService
    ){
         setTimeout( () => 
        this.storage.change(),2000);
    }

    change(){
        this.storage.change();
    }

}
```

#### OtherComponent.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from "./storage.service";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

@Component({
  selector: 'other',
  template: `<p>{{name}}</p>`,
})

export class OtherComponent  { 
    name:string;
    subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(
        private storage : StorageService,
    ){
        this.name = this.storage.name;
        this.subscription = this.storage.nameChange.subscribe((value) => { 
            this.name = value; 
        });

    }

     ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, "But somehow subscribe is not firing if the component is not a child of parent component." what child, what parent ?

Comment: if I fire **this.storage.change();** from AppComponent, all the components are receiving the subscription but calling it from a component does not works.

Comment: I am using systemjs

Comment: I am giving a scenario, please suggest me how to achieve it. I want to fetch **User** details via an AJAX call from Component A and store the data in $rootScope like thing. Then I will go to Component B and retrieve the data from $rootScope. I don't want to fire AJAX again.  But $rootScope is not available in Angular2, So how to achieve same functionality.? Please help.

Comment: you don't need a special service to do that , in your userService : `users:Observable<User[]>=this.http.get(url).map(resp=>resp.json()).repeat().share()` then users is an observable that will repeat indefinitely without another http call.

Comment: A plunker if you can please. :)

Comment: I suggest you to update your question to reflect that statement and then I'll make a plunkr ;).